# Is it OK to have hidden ad link in an answer?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, advertising, external-links

Was reading [this question](https://web.archive.org/web/20170308054806/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580381/the-coolest-parts-of-windows-api) (archived) and noticed that in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2580682/) there is a hyperlink to page on Amazon, to Charles Petzold's book. I have seen mentions of that book already several times.

Link:

```
http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/157231995X
```

Stack Overflow earning money from this link?
Is this paid promotion of Charles Petzold?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links?lq=1

Answer (score 87, accepted):

All links to Amazon from Stack Overflow are automatically transformed to insert the Stack Overflow affiliate link. See [Auto-inserting Stack Overflow affiliate into all Amazon book links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links?lq=1):

> To be clear: **from this point on, all Amazon book links posted on all sites will automatically be rewritten to add our affiliate link**. We have a clever affiliate redirect that geolocates the IP and redirects to the appropriate regional Amazon store (amazon.uk, amazon.ca, et cetera).

So yes, this is on purpose, yes Stack Exchange presumably earns money from these affiliate links, and no, this is not specific to that author.

Comment: That's a clever way to monetize a website that I never would've thought of.

Comment: I thought Amazon disallowed that kind of thing now.

Comment: @Flimm: [they do not disallow such links, no](https://affiliate-program.amazon.co.uk/).

Comment: That's just a link to the affiliate program, which I'm aware of. I assumed that Amazon does not allow sites to automatically convert user-generated Amazon links to affiliate links, since they would be wasting their money in that case. After some Googling it seems that this is allowed for sites, but not for extensions.

Answer (score 2):

My answer that it is not valid for a *regular* user to somehow embed a hidden link in a question, answer, comment or anything else.  On the other hand, I'm OK with it if *Stack Overflow* (as the site operator) automatically edits link to collect referral money from Amazon or whoever.  I would just want some disclosure - like

> Stack Overflow edited your link "http://amazon/blah" for the following
>   reason: blah.  The link now has the URL
>   "http://amazon/blah?referrer=stkx"